# POS migration hard fork

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, powhash

when Ethereum will switch to the proof of stack consensus mechanism as i know it will get rid of the POW going through a hard fork.

is it possible to have the similar scenario that happened before with ETC to end with a POW8ether or somthing like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**yes it's possible,** Ethereum when switch to POS(Casper) will activate the difficulty bomb making the mining process based on POW impossible. However, the miners who invested lot of money have the choice to switch to mine another currency or eventually keep mining ethereum and in this case they could fork Ethereum to keep the POW.